# React and canvas reactivity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I would like to integrate canvas to my React app.

```
const Comp = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  let canvasCtx = null;

  useEffect(() => {
    canvasCtx = ref.current.getContext('2d');
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <canvas ref={ref} width="800" height="800">
      </canvas>
      <Circle ctx={canvasCtx}></Circle>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The issue is I need the `canvas` element to be mounted first before I can get the context. The child `Circle` needs the context to work.

Here is the `Circle` code (which is not really a Circle for now...)

```
const Circle = ({ ctx }) => {
  if (ctx) {
    ctx.fillRect(25, 25, 100, 100);
    ctx.clearRect(45, 45, 60, 60);
    ctx.strokeRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
  }
  return null;
};
```

Unfortunately, the condition is never true.

How can I make sure the children are updated when the `canvasCtx` is ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make it state variable so when you will update, it will re-render the component

```js
const Comp = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  let [canvasCtx, setCanvasCtx] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCanvasCtx(ref.current.getContext('2d'));
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <canvas ref={ref} width="800" height="800">
      </canvas>
      <Circle ctx={canvasCtx}></Circle>
    </div>
  );
};
```